# Clarification on the calculation of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n!}{2^n}$

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

Consider the following solution for $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n!}{2^n}$.

\begin{aligned}
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^{n}}{n !} &=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^{n}}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n}\left(1+\Theta\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)} \\
&=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(1+\Theta\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)}\left(\frac{2 e}{n}\right)^{n} \\
& \leq \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{2 e}{n}\right)^{n} \\
& \leq \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}}=0
\end{aligned}

What motivates/justifies the transition from line 3 to line 4? How was the $\frac{1}{2^n}$ arrived to?

Comment: Just a remark: $$
\frac{{2^n }}{{n!}} = \frac{2}{1}\frac{2}{2}\frac{2}{3} \cdots \frac{2}{n} \le 2\frac{2}{n}
$$ for $n\geq 2$. Stirling's formula is really an overkill here.

Comment: You make a great point. The exercise insisted on using Stirling's formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $2e/n$ tends to zero as $n \to \infty$, it will be less than $1/2$ from some point on, and then $(2e/n)^n < (1/2)^n$.

Comment: By the same reasoning, it will also be less than 1/3 or 1/5 from some point on... Is there any significance to choosing 1/2 in particular?

Comment: @LucasTaddeus No there isn't.

Comment: Use ratio test for sequences

Comment: Any positive number ${} < 1$ could have been used in place of $1/2$.  The person writing the proof considered $1/2$ to be the "easiest" such number.  [You could confuse student even more by using $1/\pi$.]